# FacetWP group listings by custom field

Tags: plugins, wp-query, customization, custom-field

I'm working on a site that uses FacetWP for an events location page and one critical feature is not working. Last year, another dev set up a custom solution to list out FacetWP posts and have them sorted by the state they are in. They used a custom taxonomy for this, but since then, the plugin and is map add-on have had updates that broke that solution.

The dev behind FacetWP has been helping me a bit to rework the custom solution, but he's unavailable now, and I still need some help. He directed me to redo the query to cut out the custom taxonomy and use a custom field instead for the state names as that works better with the plugin. So the query for this template looks like this:

```
<?php
return array(
  'post_type' => 'location',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key' => 'state',
  'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value' => 'ASC',
    'title' => 'ASC',
  ),
);
```

This part works great and solved an earlier problem I had. I rebuilt the template's display code like this:

```
<?php
while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $state = get_field('state');
    $show_header = (empty($prev_state) || $state != $prev_state);
    $prev_state = $state;

    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $distance = facetwp_get_distance($post_id);
    $distance = (false !== $distance) ? round($distance, 1) . ' miles away' : '';
    $coords = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
    $content = get_the_content();
    ?>
  <?php if ($show_header): ?>
  <h1 class="state-name"><?php echo esc_html($state); ?></h1>
  <?php endif;?>

  <div class="post-item" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"
      data-latitude="<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>"
      data-distance="<?php echo $distance; ?>">
    <div class="post-item-content">
      <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
      <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

You can see from [the staging server where I'm testing this](http://d2slive.staging.wpengine.com/locations/) that it's almost working, but not 100% correctly. The posts are not listing by state correctly, and the state title is incorrect above the listings.

It's been a long day and my brain is just not seeing what I need to do to correct this. I could definitely use a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: glad that you found the solution for your problem but questions strongly related to plugin usage (opposed to plugin development) are just off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I'll remember that in the future. I had hoped it would be ok since it was more about the PHP than the plugin itself. Thanks!

Comment: with plugins it it hard most of the time to know when a problem is a result of a bug in the plugin, or misconfiguration. It is ok to specify the plugin as a context, but questions should be about usage of wordpress core API and relevant tools. OTOH pure php/css/html/js questions are most likely to also be off topic as many times they can apply to any framework and not just wordpress.

Comment: Makes sense. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it:

```
<?php

    $state_posts = array();

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $state = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'state', true);
        $state_posts[$state][] = $post;
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    foreach ($state_posts as $state_post => $state_title) {
?>
  <h1 class="state-name"><?php echo esc_html($state_post); ?></h1>
<?php
  foreach ($state_title as $listing => $single_listing) {
    setup_postdata($single_listing);
    $post_id = $single_listing->ID;
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $distance = facetwp_get_distance($post_id);
    $distance = (false !== $distance) ? round($distance, 1) . ' miles away' : '';
    $coords = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
    $content = get_the_content();
?>
  <div class="post-item" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>" data-distance="<?php echo $distance; ?>">
    <div class="post-item-content">
      <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
      <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I had the post data like `the_title`, `the_content`, etc. in the `while` loop when I needed it in the very last `foreach` loop in order to apply those to only the individual posts.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is list out the custom field values in a few foreach loops like so:

```
<?php

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $posts = $query->have_posts();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $distance = facetwp_get_distance($post_id);
    $distance = (false !== $distance) ? round($distance, 1) . ' miles away' : '';
    $coords = get_post_meta($post_id, 'location', true);
    $content = get_the_content();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      $state = get_field('state');
      $state_posts[$state][] = $post;
    }
}

foreach ($state_posts as $state_post => $state_title) {
  ?>
  <h1 class="state-name"><?php echo esc_html($state); ?></h1>
  <?php
  foreach ($state_title as $listing) {
    ?>
    <div class="post-item" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>"
      data-latitude="<?php echo $coords['lat']; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $coords['lng']; ?>" data-distance="<?php echo $distance; ?>">
      <div class="post-item-content">
        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <?php echo $content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look right to me at all.